# SAS Line graphs from Data in a row rather than column

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I've searched but none of the information shows how to plot a line graph from ***data that is given in a row, rather than column.***

I have data in this form:

```
Firstname Lastname Sep Oct Nov Dec Jan Feb March April May June July
```

There are 100 rows of data with individual people. I have to plot each graph for each individual starting from Sep To July. My output will be 100 individual graphs. I know how to plot if the data is in column, but that is not what i am given. Changing the data is going to be too much work. I do not have any sas codes for rows:

```
**Proc sgplot data=data1;
series x=??? ( i need mths from Sep to July here)
Series y= ?? (will be the marks from the Sep to July) 
Run;**
```

Here is how the output should look:

[image]

Comment: You're correct, you need your data in a column not a row to graph. Use PROC TRANSPOSE to reformat the data. Not sure what you mean by too much work, but ultimately its not a choice.

Comment: data step: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/modules/reshaping-data-wide-to-long-using-a-data-step/  
proc transpose: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/modules/how-to-reshape-data-wide-to-long-using-proc-transpose/

Comment: Shape the data to fit the tool -- even if it is coming from remote data such as web table, excel sheet or extract file.  Cementing your self into wide data layout with *calendar* columned values will actually be more troublesome if you have to work with multiple year, or year crossing months.

Answer (score 0):

Your table needs to be in a flat format, e.g.:

```
FirstName LastName Date

John      Smith    01JAN2018
Jane      Doe      01JAN2018
```

This can be done with `PROC TRANSPOSE.`  It is best to align your dates to a specific year/date. This will maintain the correct date order. Assume that your data is for 2018.

**Create sample data**

```
data have;
    length name $10.;
    array months[*] Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec;
    retain goal 75;

    do name = 'Mark', 'Jane', 'Jake', 'John', 'Jack', 'Jill', 'Bill', 'Jerry', 'Joseph';
        do i = 1 to dim(months);
            months[i] = round(100*rand('uniform') );
        end;

        output;
    end;

    drop i;
run;
```

**Solution**

```
proc sort data=have;
    by name goal;
run;

proc transpose data=have 
               out=have_transposed;
    by name goal;

    var Jan--Dec;
run;

data want;
    set have_transposed;

    Month = input(cats('01', _NAME_, 2018), DATE9.);

    rename COL1 = Score;

    format month monname3.;
    drop _NAME_;
run;    

proc sgplot data=want;
    by name;

    series x=month y=goal / name='goal' lineattrs=(color=salmon thickness=2);
    series x=month y=score / name='series' lineattrs=(thickness=2);
    scatter x=month y=score / markerattrs=(symbol=circlefilled) name='points';
    keylegend 'series' 'goal';
run;
```